# How to access a child's child of a parent Node

Tags: java, xml

I have a challenge accessing a child's child of a parentNode. Below is the xml i am working with:

```
String response = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<closure>
    <amount>1055296.0000</amount>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <unit>2</unit>          
    <year>2012</year>
    <taxes>
        <tax>
            <descript>FEE LEVY</descript>               
            <taxAmt> 
                <amt>30304.0000</amt>
                <currency>USD</currency>                    
            </taxAmt>
            <taxCode>SUR</taxCode>
        </tax>
        <tax>
            <descript>MED LEVY</descript>               
            <taxAmt>
                <amt>25125.0000</amt>
                <currency>USD</currency>                    
            </taxAmt>
            <taxCode>CIS</taxCode>
        </tax>          
    </taxes>
</closure>";
```

Below is the code i have tried:

```
     DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
     InputSource src = new InputSource();`
     src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response));
     Document doc = builder.parse(src);
     String amount =doc.getElementsByTagName("amount").item(0).getTextContent();
     NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("tax"); 
     for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
     { 
     Node childNode = nodeList.item(i); 
     }
```

Please how do i get descript, taxAmt and taxCode inside the element tax?

Comment: Please indent your XML.

Comment: @Kaushal28... I have indented my xml well.

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("amount").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i actually want to get <descript>, <taxAmt> and <taxCode>. Kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to solve the isssue i had:
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource src = new InputSource();
    src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response));
    Document doc = builder.parse(src);

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("tax"); 
Node node;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
    {           
        Node childNode = nodeList.item(i); 
        NodeList nodelist  = childNode.getChildNodes();

         for(int ii = 0; ii < nodelist.getLength(); ii++)
         {             
               node  = nodelist.item(ii);
                if(node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
                {  
                    node.getTextContent();
                }            
                else if(node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("taxAmount"))
                {
                    NodeList taxAmountNodelist = node.getChildNodes();
                   for(int iii = 0; iii < taxAmountNodelist.getLength(); iii++)
                   { 
                       Node taxAmountNode  = taxAmountNodelist.item(iii);
                         if(taxAmountNode.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("amount"))
                         {
                            taxAmountNode.getTextContent();                            
                         } 
                   }
                }                
            else if(node.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("taxcode"))
            {                            
                node.getTextContent();                                                            
            }
         } 


    }
```